# How to modify a nested object with jq

Tags: json, jq

Given this

```
{
  "some": "property",
  "nested": {
    "hello": "world"
  }
}
```

I'd like to get this result with jq

```
{
  "some": "property",
  "nested": {
    "hello": "world",
    "freshly": "added"
  }
}
```

So how can I add the freshly added field ? I don't know how many properties are at root level (and I want to keep them all), I only know the name of the nested object (here "nested"), the name of the property I'd like to add (here "freshly") and its value.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Just assign the new value to the nested object.

```
.nested.freshly = "added"
```

Answer (score 7):

Well I found out myself how to do it. If you have a better solution, you're more than welcome to give it here.

```
jq '.nested=(.nested + {"freshly": "added"})'
```

Comment: While Jeff's answer is more to the point, this is also very useful when the map containing the keys is generated in some other way. That said, I would just write it as `.nested += {"freshly": "added"}`

Answer (score 2):

You can also do simply

```
.nested += {freshly: "added"}
```

Then you can add multiple nested keys at once